# Windows Azure Publish Website- "Unable to get subscription information. An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: azure, web, publish

I'm following this tutorial here
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/#nextsteps

I'm at step 3. I click import, I can see I'm signed in with my MSDN ultimate account (I get $150 per month to spend on Azure). I then click New, and when the dialogue opens I cannot enter anything (all boxes are disabled), along with an error message in red:

http://gyazo.com/17eb15f07d54e2867cd5f21d377f04aa

Why is this? It is something with my MSDN account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get also this problem if your MS account is registered with more than one Azure subscription. It appears Visual studio gets confused if your account is attached to more than one subscription and tries to use the wrong one for accessing the Azure API.

If it occurs you need to ignore the advice from @Dev Trails and instead do the following:

> 1. In Server Explorer, right-click Windows Azure node > Manage Subscriptions
> 2. In the Certificates tab Import a new subscription certificate (this will take you to the current link on the Azure portal to download your
>      certificate)
> 3. In the Subscriptions tab, on the specific subscription that fails,
>      select the drop-down and choose the certificate instead of the
>      username.

Refreshing the Azure explorer should now show your databases etc without error.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Visual Studio 2013. Found an answer posted [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809531/create-a-site-on-windows-azure-unable-to-get-subscription-information-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added):

> To workaround the issue, you can try the following:
>
> 1. In Server Explorer, right-click Windows Azure node > Manage Subscriptions
> 2. If you are signed-in to Azure, you will see the same subscription show up both in the Accounts tab and in the Certificates tab. Remove the one in the Certificates tab.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015: delete all MS Account from VS. Add once again.